# How to modify SelectionArea's selected text before its copied to clipboard?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

There are a few `Text` widgets wrapped with a `Column` and a `SelectionArea`.

I can now select all these widgets together and copy them to the clipboard.

How can I modify the text that gets copied to the clipboard when a user taps on 'copy'?

Comment: Same question here